# Check input value against an array

Tags: backbone.js, input

I am using this plugin for my autocomplete form:
http://www.planbox.com/blog/news/updates/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-for-backbone-js.html

Instead of checking only one item, as in the code below (`if (inputVal == 'bakaxel')`),
I would like to check the selected value against the entire collection

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id:"AB", name:"Alberta"},
    {id:"AD", name:"Album"},
    {id:"BA", name:"barn"},
    {id:"BC", name:"bak"},
    {id:"BD", name:"baby"},
    {id:"BE", name:"band"},
    {id:"BF", name:"bakaxel"},
    {id:"BG", name:"batteri"},
    {id:"BH", name:"barbie"},
    {id:"MB", name:"Manitoba"},
    {id:"AP", name:"Armed Forces Pacific"}
]);

$('input.search').autocomplete({
    collection: collection,
    attr: 'name',
    noCase: true,
    ul_class: 'search_options tr_list',
    ul_css: {'z-index':1234}
});

$('input.search').each(function(){
    $(this).blur(function(){
        var inputVal = $('input.search').val();

        if (inputVal == 'bakaxel') {
            $('#search_result_page').load('searchResult.html');
            $('#searchPage').addClass('hidden');
        }      

    });
});
```

I tried this, but I'd rather not create the ar array again, just use the backbone collection:

```
$('input.search').each(function(){

    $(this).blur(function(){
        var inputVal = $('input.search').val();
        var ar = ["Alberta", "Album", "barn", "bak", "baby", "band", "bakaxel", "batteri", "barbie", "Manitoba", "Armed Forces Pacific"];

        if (jQuery.inArray(inputVal, ar) != -1) {
            $('#search_result_page').load('searchResult.html');
            $('#searchPage').addClass('hidden');
        } 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone proxies Underscore functions and most notably in your case http://underscorejs.org/#where

> **where** *_.where(list, properties)*
>   Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the
>   key-value pairs listed in properties.

Your test could be written as

```
var matches = collection.where({
    name: inputVal
});
if (matches.length>0) {
...
}
```

Or as @mu suggested in the comments, you could just check the existence of the input with http://underscorejs.org/#find

```
var found = collection.find(function(model) {
    return model.get('name') === inputVal
});
if (found) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you're just checking existence then [`collection.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) might be a better fit but it probably won't make much difference in practice.